# How reference a namespace at the root of my Python package?

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

I am creating a local Python package to pip install into a series of applications.

I have a file in a subfolder of the package

`\src\my_package\model\do_stuff_x.py`

and a file at the root

`\src\my_package\request_models.py`

When I try to use `from request_models import MyModel` in `do_stuff_x.py`, I get the error

`No module named 'request_models'`

How do I properly reference a model at the root of my pip installed package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need the `__init__.py` files to turn those directories into packages. Here is the file structure:

```
my_package
├── __init__.py
├── model
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── do_stuff.py
└── request_models.py
```

Then, inside `do_stuff.py`:

```py
from ..request_models import MyModel
```

What you see there is relative import, which works within a package.